# Select MAX () and GROUP BY ... Missing link between columns

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by

I am still at beginner level on SQL programming so please bear in mind ...

My database is similar to the below:

```html
+---------------------+------------+--------+------+--+
| Date                | FileName   | Type   | File |  |
+---------------------+------------+--------+------+--+
| 2023-06-15 08:03:04 | InputParam | Param  | .... |  |
+---------------------+------------+--------+------+--+
| 2023-06-15 09:15:34 | InputParam | Param  | .... |  |
+---------------------+------------+--------+------+--+
| 2023-06-16 01:05:07 | OutputSet  | Set    | .... |  |
+---------------------+------------+--------+------+--+
| 2023-06-16 11:22:04 | ConnConfig | Config | .... |  |
+---------------------+------------+--------+------+--+
| 2023-06-16 17:33:00 | ConnConfig | Config | .... |  |
+---------------------+------------+--------+------+--+
| 2023-06-17 06:06:28 | ConnConfig | Config | .... |  |
+---------------------+------------+--------+------+--+
```

I need to create a table showing all the above columns but with the most recent entries only, thus, similar to the below:

```html
+---------------------+------------+--------+------+--+
| Date                | FileName   | Type   | File |  |
+---------------------+------------+--------+------+--+
| 2023-06-15 09:15:34 | InputParam | Param  | .... |  |
+---------------------+------------+--------+------+--+
| 2023-06-16 01:05:07 | OutputSet  | Set    | .... |  |
+---------------------+------------+--------+------+--+
| 2023-06-17 06:06:28 | ConnConfig | Config | .... |  |
+---------------------+------------+--------+------+--+
```

My strategy was to:

SELECT MAX(Date) As Date, FileName, Type, File
FROM myTable
WHERE File IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY FileName;

However, this is not holding the relation between the FileName and the File. The Date and FileName are filtered and grouped as expected.

Please note that File is BLOB type.

Comment: Do you mean the last entry for each value in `FileName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
WITH RankedEntries AS (
    SELECT
        Date,
        FileName,
        Type,
        File,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FileName ORDER BY Date DESC) AS rn
    FROM
        myTable
    WHERE
        File IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    Date,
    FileName,
    Type,
    File
FROM
    RankedEntries
WHERE
    rn = 1;
```

Here,
`RankedEntries` CTE assigns a row number to each entry within each FileName partition based on the `Date` in descending order

Query selects the rows from the `RankedEntries` CTE where `rn` is equal to 1. This ensures that you get the most recent entry for each FileName while retaining all the columns `(Date, FileName, Type, and File)`.

Comment: The OP says to be a beginner, maybe a little explanation would be good

Comment: Or just link-in one of the canonical answers with lot more details and approaches for different versions of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by all the non-aggregated fields like this:

SELECT MAX(Date) As Date, FileName, Type, File
FROM myTable
WHERE File IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY FileName, Type, File;